# Number Counter Not Updating HTML on KeyCode Press

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I'm trying to get my `<p>` of 1980 in my HTML to move up by one every time up is pressed. It works the first time using the code below and 1981 is printed in my document, but every move afterwards returns the following error: Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is null. I'd really appreciate some advice on this.

Many thanks!!!

```
x=0; //Setting cursor counter

//Adding event listener that adds 1 to the numberArray every time the user presses up.
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
if (evt.keyCode === 38) {
    //alert('The "UP" key is being held down...?');
    x+=1;
    arrayGroup = eval ("numberArray"+(x));
    var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
    var child = document.getElementById("p1");
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode('198'+x+'');
    para.appendChild(node);
    parent.replaceChild(para,child);

    drawpic();

    }
});
```

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks for the edit, apologies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is because you are replacing `child` node with `para` node. When you call `var child = document.getElementById('p1')` there is no node with that id found, which causes error.

You need to set the id on the new `<p>` tag after you've replaced the node having that id.

Try this:

```
x=0; 
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
if (evt.keyCode === 38) {
    x+=1;
    arrayGroup = eval ("numberArray"+(x));
    var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
    var child = document.getElementById("p1");
    var para = document.createElement("p");        
    var node = document.createTextNode('198'+x+'');
    para.appendChild(node);
    parent.replaceChild(para,child);
    para.setAttribute('id', 'p1');
    drawpic();

   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance, it has gotten me back on track :-)